# GAE detailed status page

Tags: google-app-engine

There is a [status page](http://code.google.com/status/appengine/) showing the system status but where the GAE team publishes detailed status about issues?

For example in the last days there was high error rate and high latency but there is no public explanation by the GAE team for the reason and when it is going to be solved

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There have already been many complaints about this, check the mailing list.

http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/

You're probably better off filing a production issue, or complaining on the mailing list.  This doesn't look like a Stack Overflow kinda question.

edit: some downtime announcements are on the notification list, you should probably subscribe to that as well.

http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-downtime-notify

Comment: Already done both (entered a production issue and checked the groups) but I thought that I'm missing something as there is no reference by the GAE team to those issues.